# How can I manually release a updlock on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

What I want to do :

```
begin tran

update table_x updlock
   set x = y
where z = a

exec process_stuff @input_parameters

--here i want to release the updlock so it becomes available for other transactions again.

exec process_other_stuff @input_parameters

commit tran
```

Any idea how to do this? I want to keep everything within one transaction so I don't want to commit halfway (kinda beats the purpose of an explicit transaction in this example).

Comment: Commit the transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. however I dont want to commit the transaction (i'll update the question to make that clear). maybe nested transaction may work as well? but the question is as soon as you commit a sub-transaction will it release all updlocks within that sub-transaction or will it wait before the entire transaction is committed?

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have nested transactions; it just fakes those by incrementing and decrementing a counter. There is no way to manually or explicitly release locks (other than app locks, but those have their own complications); a lock is either released when it's no longer needed or held explicitly until the transaction end if specified. What you can do is perform an update that "claims" the row, and then another one at the end to release it again. Obviously some care must be taken that this works correctly.

Comment: There is no concept of *partially* committing a transaction that I know of in SQL Server

Comment: What's the purpose for the hint? In the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, an `UPDATE` statement will acquire update locks by default on rows touched and release the lock if the row is not updated. Only the exclusive locks on rows actually updated will remain until the transaction is committed.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert, by the way, no RDBMS can have nested transaction nor sub-transaction, because by definition a transaction is an atomic execution of code and by nature, anything that is atomic cannot be also subatomic ! But this is not a fake... just a way to solve a problem of multiple frontiers of transactions... The algorithm choose by MS SQL Server is based on the asymetric model : COMMIT does not validate the transaction until all BEGIN TRAN has been closed, but ROLLBACK immediatly unvalidate the explicit transactionnal state... Because any explicit transaction is a state of the session.